# How to create a double array with n element?

Tags: arrays, vb.net

In vb.net I can do this

```
Dim addition = {0.0, 0.0, 0.0}
```

Here, {0.0, 0.0, 0.0} is an array of double with 3 elements.

What about if I want a variable number of element. Say elNum contains the number of element in an array and I want an array of double, initialized to say, 0.0, with elNum number of elements.

A way to do so is to do `Dim addition(elNum) as double.`

That's awkward. Is there another way to do so? Something that works as an expression rather than just declaration?

I am looking something more elegant.

Something like

`arraydouble(n)` where `arraydouble` is a function that given an argument would yield an array of double initialized at 0with n elelements

I wonder if something simple and built in is there.

Comment: if you use a `List(Of Double)` you dont have to worry about how many, when, if it will grow etc

Comment: It's not really clear why you cant use `Dim addition(elNum) as double`.

Comment: If you don't know what the values are at that point, how can you write it as an expression anyway? I don't understand why the `Dim() As Double` syntax is awkward?

Comment: because it's not an expression.

Comment: What are you expecting you should be able to do? Initialize an array that's variable sized? `Dim addition(elNum) as double` does that. Do you want to specify the starting values of your array? That's a different question entirely.

Answer (score 2):

Arrays are not very elegant to begin with when it comes to resizing them to hold more or less data.

A `List` avoids the issue entirely and provides a way to store typed data (int, bool or even class objects).  The size is internally managed so it grows as needed.

```
Private addList As New List(Of Double)
```

To add values:

```
addList.Add(0.0)
addList.Add(1.23)
addList.Add(3.14)
```

If 3 turns out not to be enough, just add more.  Reference them like an array:

```
For n As Integer = 0 to addList.Count-1
    Console.WriteLine(addList(n).ToString())
Next n
' or:
For Each d As Double in addList
    Console.WriteLine(d.ToString())
Next
```

To remove an element (consider the code required to do this with an array):

```
addList.RemoveAt(1)      ' remove 1.23
```

You can also sort, randomize, convert and query them extensively.  For instance, if something else absolutely has to have this data in array form you can use `addList.ToArray()`

Answer (score 1):

You could use `ReDim` or `ReDim Preserve` if you want to keep values:

```
Dim x

ReDim x(5)
    x(5) = "test"
    MsgBox UBound(x)
    MsgBox x(UBound(x))

elNum = 6

ReDim Preserve x(elNum)
    x(6) = "test2"
    MsgBox x(5)
    MsgBox UBound(x)
    MsgBox x(UBound(x))
```